# Prepare signing/verifying module from node js crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, signing

I'm working on a node crypt module that will signing/verifying. I have managed the verifying module:

```
'use strict';

const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'key.pub'));
const encryptDataPath = path.join(__dirname, 'encryptData.txt');
let encryptData = fs.readFileSync(encryptDataPath).toString();

//console.log(encryptData);


// start decoding
const plainEncryptData = Buffer.from(encryptData, 'base64').toString();


const [signatureb64, contentb64] = plainEncryptData.split('\n');


const signature = Buffer.from(signatureb64, 'base64');
const content = Buffer.from(contentb64, 'base64').toString();

const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verifier.update(content);
verifier.end();

const isValid = verifier.verify(publicKey, signature);

if (!isValid) {
    console.log('not valid');
} else {    
    console.log(content);
}
```

Here is the public key (pub.key):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApuI1XlPkYos3WsSeVPtS
l1Q2k8GnLEO5vFZ4EuSghMbqI+yE0tWVEaiptdV3KgERaALRXmH+IFrHqvSRjKQC
1ORUarBU5ntWbNEr713R3K0BPOzz9OOoWHdk+Wmr4ViOTk0iD1u4bw/97RpyMoBm
+pXeBLHbEESK2kelk+LEmKUoY5nXp6KzZV5wxgD5QweZheU7mjXL5WMpIBJva8kp
RZMYXEF+uSZIep0q5FHEo2AazGUMAU3GjY/dpXisLmtleOa1xlKZmkvaXl/D2Mhb
BBqPbDMa72ToZg2J8K5UP9zXUP41FHr7o9rwSJ2uOkuZPg5nhDXeoVbrJwxP/U1M
nQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Here is encryptData.txt (encrypt data)

```
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
```

Now, I am trying to create its signing module which will create encrypt data as same as encryptData.txt:

```
'use strict';

const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'key.pub'));

let content = {}
content.type = "bronze";
content.customerId = "16COVRSc9x21fCHnE";
content.expireAt = 1626576362000;
content.isTrial = true;
content.licenseKey = "c9295b69-bee6-431a-8d7d-0b740f01ca2d";
content.createdAt = 1625366769531;


const encryptDataPath = path.join(__dirname, 'encryptData.txt');
let a = fs.readFileSync(encryptDataPath).toString();

// signing
const signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
signer.update(content);
signer.end();

const signature = signer.sign(publicKey, 'base64');

console.log('sign: ', signature);
```

But when I run this encrypt module, it is throwing this error:

```
internal/crypto/util.js:97
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type object
    at Sign.update (internal/crypto/sig.js:49:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/www/node-encrpt/encode.js:23:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I can not figure out why this occurs.

How can I complete the encrypt module?

Comment: This is not about encryption/decryption, but about signing/verifying. These are two completely different things. By the way, signing is done with the private key and not with the public key. The public key is used for verification.

Comment: Thanks, @user9014097, I have updated the question title. Can I use any private key to generate the same encryptedData.txt?

Comment: _encryptData.txt_ contains some data and its signature. The same _encryptData.txt_ therefore means the same signature for the same data. The signature in turn depends on the key, data and padding. In the code PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is used. This creates the same signature for the same key and the same data. I.e. you can create the same signature for the same data if you apply the private key with which the signature was created in _encryptData.txt_.

Comment: @user9014097 can I have to use `const signature = Buffer.from(signatureb64, 'base64');` to generate private key? I don't have any idea, how can I make that private key?

Comment: You cannot simply reconstruct a private key from a signature and/or a public key. If that were possible, the asymmetric procedures would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is quite straightforward: this line...

```
signer.update(content);
```

... attempts to process an Object (value of `content`), but it cannot: `update` doesn't expect to care about proper serialization of passed data. It's up to you to decide how to handle this.

One common approach is using JSON as a serialization format:

```
signer.update(JSON.stringify(content));
```

But in fact you can use any function that is able to map object's content onto a string, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. These are the only types expected by `signer.update()`.

Comment: Now it is throwing another error:

```internal/crypto/sig.js:84
  const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding

```

Comment: What's the format of public/private keys you use?